# open accordion. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I have a text field, in which I can filter the contents of the header of the accordion, as well as the content. I would like it when I am typing something, and if there is coincidence the accordion expands, but there is coincidence the accordions should be closed. how can I do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/3e9arqqe/

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.pregunta">
    <uib-accordion close-others="true">
     <div ng-repeat="faq in faqs | filter: search.pregunta">
        <div class="col-sm-11" >
          <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="faq.open">
              <uib-accordion-heading  >
                  <span  ng-click="ignoreClick($event);" ><a  href='' click-to-edit item="faq" ng-model='faq.pregunta'   typeinput='textarea' >{{faq.pregunta}}</a></span> <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': faq.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !faq.open}"></i>
              </uib-accordion-heading>
              <span click-to-edit item="faq" ng-model="faq.respuesta" >{{faq.respuesta}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </ui/div>
      </div>
     </uib-accordion>
```

Comment: Do you want the accordions without a match to show up collapsed and not  get filtered out?

Comment: @CodeWarrior When they reappear, they should appear closed

Answer (score 1):

You want to open the accordions that match the search, right? Not completely hide them?

You can use an expression in the `is-open` attribute eg. like this:

`is-open="search.pregunta && faq.pregunta.indexOf(search.pregunta) !== -1"`

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpy9kydo/)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to have the filtered results be expanded, you'll have to replace the `is-open="faq.open"` with `is-open="search.pregunta?true:false"`
and replace `ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': faq.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !faq.open}"` with `ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': search.pregunta, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !search.pregunta}"`

We're basically determining the expand/collapse state on whether the search text is empty or not.

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CodeWarrior404/0pmrLgm0/1/)

Comment: great! but I get an error in the console.. you can try.. :(